# KeyError: 'column_name'

Tags: python, numpy, keyerror

I am writing a python code, it should read the values of columns but I am getting the KeyError: 'column_name' error. Can anyone please tell me how to fix this issue.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pandas as pd


### For the purposes of this example, we store feature data from our
### dataframe `df`, in the `f1` and `f2` arrays. We combine this into
### a feature matrix `X` before entering it into the algorithm.

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Desktop\data.csv')

print (df)

#df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

"""
saved_column = df.Distance_Feature
saved_column = df.Speeding_Feature

print(saved_column)
"""

f1 = df['Distance_Feature'].tolist()
f2 = df['Speeding_Feature'].tolist()

print(f1)
print(f2)

X=np.matrix(zip(f1,f2))

print(X)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(X)
```

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: KeyError: 'Distance_Feature'

Comment: It is not reading the column_name and values from the excel

Comment: you can pass column names when reading csv file. pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Desktop\data.csv',names=columns_list)

Answer (score 0):

Asumming 'C:\Users\Desktop\data.csv' contains the following data

```
Distance_Feature Speeding_Feature
1   2
3   4
5   6
 ...
```

Change

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Desktop\data.csv')
```

to

```
    df = pd.read_csv("data.txt",names=["Distance_Feature","Speeding_Feature"],sep= "\s+|\t+|\s+\t+|\t+\s+",header=1) 
    # Here it is assumed white space separator, if another separator is used change `sep`.
```