# Python KeyError: 'column name'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the data file which looks like this -

```
[Table 1]
Terms         Author        Frequency
Hepatitis     Christopher   2
Acid          Subrata       1
Acid          Kal           3
Kinase        Pramod        31
Kinase        Steve         5
Kinase        Sharon        10
Acid          Rob           5
Acid          Christopher   2
Hepatitis     Sharon        3
```

which I want to convert in a frequency matrix like this -

```
Terms       Christopher     Subrata   Kal    Pramod     Steve    Sharon    Rob      
Hepatitis       2              0       0       0          0         3        0
Acid            2              0       3       0          0         0        5
Kinase          0              0       0       31         5         10       0
```

Now I have figured out how to do that and I am using this code for that -

```
 a = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\robert\\Desktop\\Python Project\\Publications Data\\New Merged Title Terms Corrected\\Python generated file\\Terms_Frequency_File.csv")
 b = a.groupby(['Terms']).apply(lambda x:x.set_index(['Terms','Author']).unstack()['Frequency'])
```

and this worked absolutely fine till yesterday but today I generated the [Table 1] data again as I had to add one additional author to the data and trying to make a frequency matrix again like in [Table 2] but it's giving me this silly error -

```
KeyError: 'Terms'
```

I am pretty sure this has to do something with the index column in the dataframe or some white space issues in the index column(in this case 'Terms' column). 
I tried to read several answers on this like this - [KeyError: 'column_name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640677/keyerror-column-name) and this - [Key error when selecting columns in pandas dataframe after read_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35831496/key-error-when-selecting-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-after-read-csv) and tried those methods but these aren't helping.

Any help on this will be much appreciated! Thanks much!

Comment: What does `print(a.columns)` give you?

Comment: You should be using pivot table here.  Try `pd.pivot_table(df, index='Terms', columns='Author', values='Frequency', fill_value=0)`  In your code, `Terms` doesn't exist in the context you have selected when you try to set_index

Comment: You can also use `crosstab` here: `pd.crosstab(df.Terms, df.Author, values=df.Frequency, aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)`

Comment: @HarvIpan - It's giving me this -   `Index([''FINGER-LOOP'', 'Kukolj G', '1'], dtype='object')`

Comment: Those are clearly the columns to a different dataframe than you have posted..

Comment: @spideypack, there is no overlap at all with the column names you have pasted here to the dataframe posted in the question. Are you sure you have not overwritten your variable `a` somewhere in your script?

Comment: It's giving me `Index(['Terms', 'Author', 'Frequency'], dtype='object')`. Sorry I was opening 2nd file of the same context. Now it's the correct file but still giving me the same error `KeyError: 'Terms'`

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem as you. I've observed that if I change the data in .csv format in OpenOffice program then the error occurs. Instead of that I've downloaded the data from the Internet and I edited the data in simple Notepad++ editor. Then it works normally. I know that perhaps this solution doesn't help in you case, but maybe you should change the text editor or program that supports .csv files.

Comment: what if I am opening it in a dataframe?